# WSO2 ESB - Making a sequence wait/pause

Tags: multithreading, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a use case where I need a sequence to wait for a period of time before it continues. Basically it is a "Thread.Sleep(x)", but this would mean the Thread is not available for the Thread pool. This could have consequences for high load systems. So therefore I have two questions:

1) What would be the best way to implement this use case? 
2) How much of a burden would using Thread.Sleep be for WSO?

Alternative solutions, for example using topic and stuff are also welcome :)

Hope you guys can help!

Answering the questions in the responses:
We are sending requests to an external system and an offline data store (ODS; DSS component of WSO2). The external system has precedense, but when it doesn't return within one second we want the ODS to answer the request.

Alternative paths:
- The ODS is offline, in this case the system has to wait for the external system for a longer time;
- The external system returns after some time, althought the ODS result has been send to the requester we still want the response of the external system to update our ODS.

We are currently investigating clone and aggregator.

Comment: If you can provide the exact use case on why you want to hold the thread, we can provide you with a better solution.!

Comment: Yes. We need to know your use case as to why you need to pause your request. I just gave a one possible answer.

Comment: Hi, let me clarify. We are sending requests to an external system and an offline data store (DSS component of WSO2). The external system has precedense, but when it doesn't return within one second we want the ODS to answer the request.

Alternative paths:
-The ODS is offline, in this case the system has to wait for the external system for a longer time;
-The external system returns after some time, althought the ODS result has been send to the requester we still want the response of the external system to update our ODS.

We are currently investigating clone and aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, `Thread.sleep()`, the first thing came to my mind is using a [Class Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator). This would be an easy way to write custom logic and add a sleep.

The sample for "[Writing your own Custom Mediation in Java](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+380%3a+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java)" will help you to learn the steps for writing a Class Mediator.

You need to copy the Jar containing custom mediator class to `repository/components/lib/`

When you use thread sleep inside your mediation logic, the request will hang for the specified time period.

This may impact your performance. But you should be able to [tune the parameters](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Performance+Tuning) for your needs.

It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Hi Isuru, thanks for your response. Regarding the Thread.Sleep there are several solutions to implement this (even using the script mediator), thanks for your implementation guidelines!

The real question however, is when will this impact performance? In our Use Case we will have a wait of 1 second. The question is, how fast will this exhaust the Thread Pool. And primary: are there better solutions within WSO2, for example an async implementation using for example java.util.Timer...